# Bookmarklet - capturing a button click on a webpage

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am more or less a complete beginner. What I want to do is use a bookmarklet to capture when a specific html button on a page is clicked and then start a timer. How would I go about that in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generators like [this](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) to convert your JavaScript into a bookmarklet.

Example:

This script logs the first button on the page when it's clicked:

```
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick=function(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```

And after conversion, this bookmarklet does the same after injected into a page.

```
javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.querySelector(%22input%5Btype%3Dbutton%5D%22).onclick%3Dfunction(e)%7Bconsole.log(e)%7D%7D)()
```

Comment: "every button" — No, that's the *first* button on the page.

Comment: sorry, changed the description.  My intention was to show the concept

Comment: The generator looks useful, thanks. How would you log a specific button by name, for example?

Comment: give it an id or find out what id it has and use document.getElementById('the_id_you_gave_the_element')